# Clarity on definition and iteration of objects in functions

Tags: python, function, loops, object, iteration

The function below is defined this way that it adds numbers from o to n value.

for loop be default iterates over the elements it defines. By x in range(n+1) it takes up numbers individually from 0 onward and x is defined this way

```py
def sum1(n):
         final_sum = 0
         for x in range(n+1):
                 final_sum +=1

        return final_sum
```

I expect the output of sum1(5) to be 6, but the actual output is 15.

Any ideas on how to redefine/correct the output?

Comment: It actually is 6, just fix your indentation by making sure the return statement is outside the for loop

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh If x in range(n+1) is taken shouldn't it sum all numbers from 0 to n.

Comment: If you define `n=9` it will

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh if I use sum1(9) it gives 10, it should give sum of numbers from 0 to 9 which is 45

Comment: Then you need to do `final_sum +=x` because right now you are incrementing it by 1, also your question is `I expect the output of sum1(5) to be 6, but the actual output is 15.` but I think it should be the other way round

Answer (score 1):

The code returns a value of 6 only when you pass 5.

`for x in range(n+1)` - this statement loops through the code from x= 0 to 5. 
For each value of x, final_sum is being incremented by 1 with the statement final_sum += 1

```
def sum1(n):
    final_sum = 0
    for x in range(n+1):
        final_sum +=1
​
    return final_sum

sum1(5)
6
```